# View and variables

Tags: php, kohana-3

Im new in Kohana framework.

I want create controller and display variables in view.

My Controller Start.php:

```
    <?php defined('SYSPATH') or die('No direct script access.');

class Controller_Start extends Controller_Template {

    public function action_index()
    {
        $view = View::factory('start')
                    ->set('title', array('tytul 1', 'tytul 2'));

                $this->response->body($view);
    }

}
```

in APPPATH/views have Start.php:

```
<h1><?php echo $title[0] ?></h1>
```

When I open site have error:

```
View_Exception [ 0 ]: The requested view template could not be found
```

When I display data from action with:

```
$this->response->body('test');
```

when I open site have 'test'

What is wrong with my view?

Comment: Try to use `->bind` instead of `->set` when you call your view in your controller.

Comment: And you could also try using `$this->template->content = $view` instead of `$this->response->body($view);`

Comment: I changed, but still same problem.

Comment: It's been a long time since I've done Kohana, but it seems it cannot find your view, in your `APPPATH/views` do you have a folder named `start` and a view named `start.php` (make sure it is in lowercase)

Comment: And when you call your view make sure to call `start/start.php` you could also put start.php in the APPPATH/view folder and call it like with View::factory('start')

Comment: I tried: APPPATH/view/start.php, APPPATH/view/start/start.php, APPPATH/view/Start/Start.php, APPPATH/view/start/Start.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your controller is missing the template definition, Piotr.

What you have to do in your Controller is to define what view your controller need to use:

```
class Controller_Start extends Controller_Template {

    // This has to be defined
    public $template = 'start';

    public function action_index()
    {
        $this->template->set('title', array('tytul 1', 'tytul 2'));

        // No need to do this if you're extending Controller_Template
        // $this->response->body($view);
    }
}
```

`my_view` is the filename (without the .php extension) of a template file located in your `/application/views` folder. If it's in a subfolder, then provide it in there, e.g.:

```
public $template = 'subfolder/start';
```

Note that it has to be defined as string, as the [`Controller_Template::before()`](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide-api/Controller_Template#before) method will transform it to a [View object](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide-api/View). This means that you do not have to create your own `$view` object within the `action_index()`, unless you want to override the default one. Then you'd need to do something like:

```
class Controller_Start extends Controller_Template {

    public function action_index()
    {
        $view = View::factory('start')
                    ->set('title', array('tytul 1', 'tytul 2'));

        $this->template = $view;

        // And that's it. Controller_Template::after() will set the response
        // body for you automatically
    }
}
```

If you want to have full control over the template and don't want Kohana to interfere I'd suggest not extending the `Controller_Template` class, but rather use the plain `Controller` and render the view yourself, e.g.:

```
class Controller_Start extends Controller {

    public function action_index()
    {
        $view = View::factory('start')
                    ->set('title', array('tytul 1', 'tytul 2'));

        // Render the view and set it as the response body
        $this->response->body($view->render());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but when i defined in my Controller: public template = 'start'; Have a error: ErrorException [ Parse Error ]: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting T_VARIABLE

Comment: Are you sure you didn't forget the `$` character before the `template` in the definition? The error indicates it's most likely a typo in the code.

Comment: Ohhh, my bad. Can You help me with next problem: i have in Controller: $view = View::factory('start')
        ->set('title', array('tytul 1', 'tytul 2')); Why have error 'Undefined variable: title'

Comment: You are assigning View variables to a newly instantiated View object which does not get passed to response. Instead of `$view = View::factory('start')->set(...)` use `$this->template->set('title', ...);`. Note, that the View object gets created for you automatically so you can start setting View variables immediately inside your action methods without instantiating it.

Comment: I updated the answer to show you complete code for your example. See the first snippet.

Comment: Glad to be of help. Remember you can always upvote good useful answers.